# RR Ultrafan: Why the dramatic change of fan blade design?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design

The Rolls Royce Ultrafan prototype has been in development for a few years and has usually been seen in the media with very distinctive curved leading edge design as such:

[image: A: highly swept blades]

However, this week (December 2022) RR have officially put it into testing, and has what appear to be more conventional looking blades:

[image: B: less swept blades]

Have they abandoned the curved set? or just trying several sets?

Source of images: [Rolls Royce Ultrafan images](https://flic.kr/s/aHsjXZFoNS)

Comment: looks like the curve that defines leading edge is identical in both pictures, with scaled up curvature at swept forward tip location that makes the first image much more stunning

Comment: @qqjkztd They are completely different.

Comment: https://flic.kr/s/aHsjXZFoNS If you look at the collection of images of the Ultrafan, it appears as if there are not two, but three different types of fan blades. Also, the fan with less swept blades is covered extensively in these images.

Comment: I think they're all the same blade. It's just the angle and scale which they are photographed accentuates the curve. It's a 3D shape, so the front-to-back variation is less obvious when looking at the engine straight on.

Comment: I'm trying to change the images in the question to ones that were taken from the same angle to better highlight the differences; they're not the same blades at all.

Comment: The problem with asking this sort of question about this sort of technology is that the designs and design choices are proprietary, and RR are unlikely to comment much. If pushed you might get a comment about the evolution of the design through testing and development, but what they won't tell you is that the curved leading edge is dramatically better aerodynamically, but impossible to manufacture in volume. Or the reverse. Information like that is not something they want to hand to their competitors.

Comment: I think engineers have taken over from the marketing department ;-)  More seriously, the latest iteration of the ultrafan has blades which are some 18% longer than the previous one (i.e. some 40% more area). I suppose that structural reasons played an important role in limiting the curvature of the leading edge.

Comment: They've been running it on the benches.... centrifugal forces fairly quickly straightened out the artistic curves the PR folks had in. :-)

[The above is not entirely in sarcasm - they probably have found having a blade which has a high degree of curvature along the aeroline and along the structural centre of rotation lines hasn't played as well as they'd hoped.]

Comment: Any design will go through many iterations, they obviously have been trying many blade designs. As for the merits of this design I would expect that information to be proprietary, and therefore you are unlikely to get an answer that isn't generic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments all :-) 
I note that the "latter" blades, although having a far less wavy leading edge, do have a form of hump in them... 
I have a few friends that work at RR, will ask if anyone has any info.